# Cloudbees separate development and production databases

Tags: database, environment, cloudbees

What's the recommended method of using a development and production database in Cloudbees? Is there a way to keep the same cloudbees-web.xml configuration and let the environment take care of connecting the proper dev/prod database?

I'm using Java/JPA/MySQL in cloudbees, or at least attempting to.

J

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use "[environments](https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/CloudBeesWebXml)" in cloudbees-web.xml

A better option (imho) is to usin SDK to [bind datasource](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Resource+Management) to application, so that exact same WAR is deployed, without unused configuration or cloudbees specific deployment descriptor (cloudbees-web.xml is then useless), but bound to a dev/prod database.

Comment: The bind does sound better. So it sounds like I make an app-test, then bind a db-test to it, likewise an "app" bound to a "db", then I don't need to make any changes after that, if I understand correctly. I just deploy the app to app-test or "app" whichever I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use property expansion in your `cloudbees-web.xml` with the form. `${property_name}`

Then you use the `bees config:set` command to define the value of `property_name` for the application id you are deploying to.

Thus whenever you deploy to the `app-dev` instance it will use the dev database and deploy to the `app-prod` instance will use the prod database.

This is also good for storing sensitive info, eg jdbc passwords as they are no longer embedded within the `.war` file

See [the cloudbees wiki](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Configuration+Parameters) for more details